# In16Array to Buffer to Int16rray

Tags: node.js, arraybuffer, typedarray

In Node.js, I was trying to cast a buffer which contains Int16Array buffer elements like below.
I have a list of numbers like following  `255,256,257,258`

```
Int16Array(4) [ 255, 256, 257, 258 ]
<Buffer ff 00 00 01 01 01 02 01>
```

So when I have a buffer like `<Buffer ff 00 00 01 01 01 02 01>` what should I do to return back to the original array as `255,256,257,258`

```
var ar = new Int16Array([255, 256, 257, 258])
var buf = Buffer.from(ar.buffer)
console.log('Here we have this', buf)
> <Buffer ff 00 00 01 01 01 02 01>

//And I need to cast back to array as [255,256,257,258]
```

Comment: `var newArr = new Int16Array(buffer)` ?

Comment: Output is -> `[ 255, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the comment says, typed arrays have constructor creating a view of an existing buffer:

```js
let bytes=Uint8Array.of(0xff,00,00,01,01,01,02,01); // <= from your log
let buf=bytes.buffer;
let shorts=new Int16Array(buf);
for(let x of shorts)
  console.log(x);
```

---

Ok, sorry, I missed the Node.js part. So, according to [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays), a `Buffer` is an `Uint8Array` for most purposes:

```
var ar = new Int16Array([255, 256, 257, 258]);
var buf = Buffer.from(ar.buffer);
console.log('Here we have this', buf);
var other = new Int16Array(buf.buffer);
for(let x of other)
  console.log(x);
```

Comment: I see that you have created bytes from Uint8Array which is ArrayBuffer
But I do have a Buffer in my example.
I am updating my question to run an example scenario

Comment: No, `buf` is ArrayBuffer which is different from Buffer in Node.js

Comment: @OzanERTÜRK ok, see the new variant.